# Script block not working in AngularJS ng-repeat section

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, hidden

The script block not working in AngularJS ng-repeat section. The issue is given below.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <input type="text" ng-model="{{user.mobile}}" ng-value ="{{user.mobile}}">

  <script>
    $(function () {
        var mobile ="{{user.mobile}}";
        alert("{{user.mobile}}");            
    });
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: AngularJS doesn't read hidden fields.  It just ignores them.  You have to put your data on the model.  Also, you're using a lot of jQuery here to do things that you simply wouldn't in Angular.  DOM manipulation would normally go in an Directive.  You might want to start with the 'official' tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00, or this one: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/.  If you're up for a book, this one is best imo: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-AngularJS-Experts-Voice-Development/dp/1430264489/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1432285869&sr=1-1&keywords=angularjs

Comment: I have updated my code, please seen, tell me how to get the value {{user.mobile}} in my <script>alert("{{user.mobile}}"></script>? need to alert for all the mobile no for users collection.

Comment: You can't.  You simply can't do it that way combining Angular expression with the jQuery script on your page like that.  I can show you how to do it in Angular, but I need to see your controller and more of your html to really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: using ng-init="alertFunc(user)" I can find all mobile no like. <div ng-repeat='item in items' ng-init="alertFunc(user)">
          {{item}} 
      </div> and $scope.alertFunc = function(user){
        alert(user.mobile);
    } but my tabs not working.

Comment: I don't see any tabs in the code in your question, so I can't help.  I'd be happy to, if you would provide a fiddle, a plunker or just some more code in your question.  Right now though, I still can't even figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok wait.., I going to setup on plunker after that i will share you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script-tags in AngularJS expression will not evaluate.
This is also not the way you want to do this. Do this in a controller, directive, but not in your DOM.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/9d-rhMiXDmg

Comment: You say, Its not possible?

Comment: No it's not possible, because that's not the way AngularJS was designed. You should use a directive or a controller.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it! If my answer was anyhow helpful to you, feel free to accept it ;-).